# Magento 2 Redirect to cart page on event 'sales_order_place_before'

Tags: magento-2.1.3

I'm using Magento 2.1.3

I have an observer 'sales_order_place_before', I want to validate some information before the payment is made and if validation is false, I want to redirect the page to 'checkout/cart' with error message.

Please see the below code , my page is response is being rendered but not redirected. Thanks!

**Observer file**

Vendor/Module/Observer/ValidateUserDetails.php

```
<?php

namespace Smartshore\Incase\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;

class ValidateUserDetails implements ObserverInterface
{ 

    protected $messageManager;
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }



    /**
    * @param EventObserver $observer
    * @return $this
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
    */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $helperFactory = $objectManager->create('Smartshore\Incase\Helper\Data');

        $order = $observer->getOrder(); 
        $orderData = $order->getData();

        $urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
        $url = $urlInterface->getUrl('/');

        $customerId = $orderData['customer_id']; 
        $customerEmail = $orderData['customer_email']; 
        $customerFirstname  = $orderData['customer_firstname']; 
        $customerMiddlename = $orderData['customer_middlename']; 
        $customerLastname = $orderData['customer_lastname']; 

        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
        $items = $cart->getItems();

        $infoArr = array();

        if (!empty($items)) {

            foreach ($items as $key => $item) {

                $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
                $customOptions = $options['options'];

                if (!empty($customOptions)) {

                    $infoArr[$customerEmail][] = array(

                        'userData' => array(
                            'email' => $customOptions[0]['value'],
                            'dob' => $customOptions[1]['value'],
                            'firstName' => $customOptions[2]['value'],
                            'lastName' => $customOptions[3]['value']
                        ),

                        'trainingId' => $customOptions[4]['value']
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($infoArr)) {

            //runCurl and get response

            $response = array('status' => 'error');

            if (isset($response['status']) && $response['status'] == 'error') {

                $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t void the payment right now.'));

                $cartUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('/');
                $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($cartUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

events.xml file

Vendor/Module/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="sales_order_place_before">
       <observer name="order_place_before" instance="Smartshore\Incase\Observer\ValidateUserDetails" shared="false" />
    </event>  
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've done most things right but you missed to add correct parameter in `getUrl()` fuction . It should be :

```
$cartUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
```

Comment: it still redirects to success page

Comment: I think you have to exit; after   $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($cartUrl);

Comment: it redirects to cart page, because of exit, suppose I want to redirect to 'contact/index/index'. if I use exit , then it wlll redirect to cart page irresepective of the url I have given. This is the main problem I'm facing

Comment: try $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($cartUrl)->sendResponse();

Comment: this is also not working, because the redirect is not working from here. with the exit expression redirect works from magento default function. I don't know from where

Comment: Is there any other event that i can work on instead of whet I'm using now?

Comment: This is the last solution i've got..
try this :
$url = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('checkout/cart/index'); // give here your controller/action
        // below code redirects to cart controller
        $observer->getControllerAction()
                    ->getResponse()
                    ->setRedirect($url);
after adding dependency injection of Magento\Framework\UrlInterface

Comment: @anujeet, did you get any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated solution:**

```
 if(Your_condition)
 {
 }
 else
 {
    $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
          $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
      exit;
 }
```

**NOTE: CODE TESTED**