# Cannot redirect to a specific page using Observer events such as sales_order_place_before, and checkout_submit_before in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer, redirect, place-order

I am currently implementing a behavior where I will check the quote items in cart, then check if it contains my custom attributes. If true, then it will redirect me to a specific page(CMS) page.
This behavior should trigger before place order is processed.

I already tried using, observer events: **sales_order_place_before** and **checkout_submit_before.** I was not successful in implementing the redirect in the observer. The place order process seems to ignore redirects from the observer.

Here is my code:

**app/code/Package/ModuleName/etc/events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_place_before">
    <observer name="observer_name" instance="Package\ModuleName\Observer\BeforePlaceOrder"/>
</event>
```

**app/code/Package/ModuleMame/Observer/BeforePlaceOrder.php**

```
 public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url */
    $url = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response */
    $response = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface');

    $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $url->getUrl('support-plan-option'); //you can change the routh path to your cms page
    $response->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
}
```

Comment: My issue is related to this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165208/magento-2-redirect-to-cart-page-on-event-sales-order-place-before                                      I already tried their suggestions from the link.

Comment: I think you are missing the `return $response;`

Comment: I aldread tried returning the whole line of $response->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();

Comment: it seems the observer disregards your redirection code, what if you put die() or exit() after you return the `$response`. check if your redirect code will work after

Comment: Hi @fnsthird, if I put die or exit, redirection won't go to my desired page  it was redirected instead to checkout cart page due to the catch condition from native magento 2 place order process.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following in your constructor:

- **`\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory`** to set the redirection and
- **`\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface`** to set the URL to redirect.

Comment: I already tried this approach but still not working.

Comment: how about using `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface` ?

Comment: also @EubieAluad can you confirm that your event observer is working?

Comment: yes @fmsthird my observer is working . Also I have tried RedirectInterface. But still redirection isn't working

Comment: can you include your code implementation in your post

Comment: I updated it. Kindly just see it my post from above. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this code in your observer to redirect on any specific page.

```
protected $_redirect;

protected $_actionFlag;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
) {
    $this->_redirect = $redirect;
    $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
}

public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    $this->_redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'support-plan-option');
}
```

Hope this may help you. :)

Comment: Hi Kishan I already tried this one, but no luck yet, thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: Can you please try to use plugin then ? That may be help.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html